# CRC-CCITT Kermit 16 in C#

Tags: c#, crc, crc16

Attempting to reverse engineer a serial port protocol. I am unable to recreate the crc-16 bytes.

**According to the documentation, this is the format of the packet**

```
48 45 4c 4f // HELO
01 00 00 01 // ARG 1
00 00 00 00 // ARG 2
00 00 00 00 // ARG 3
00 00 00 00 // ARG 4
00 00 00 00 // REQUEST BODY
5c b1 00 00 // CRC-16
b7 ba b3 b0  // Bit-wise inversion of HELO command
```

**This is the write command that was sniffed from serial monitoring**

```
48 45 4c 4f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5c b1 00 00 b7 ba b3 b0
```

I am able to recreate the packet fine, except for the 2 bytes "5c b1". According to the documentation, the 5c b1 bytes is a crc-ccit16 over the packet, with zeros in the crc-16 slot. The CRC16 function does return the 5C byte but not b1.

I am using the code below to calculate the crc:

```
  public class Crc16
{
    static ushort[] table = new ushort[256];

    public ushort ComputeChecksum(params byte[] bytes)
    {
        ushort crc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
        {
            byte index = (byte)(crc ^ bytes[i]);
            crc = (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ table[index]);
        }
        return crc;
    }

    public byte[] ComputeChecksumBytes(params byte[] bytes)
    {
        ushort crc = ComputeChecksum(bytes);
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(crc);
    }

    public Crc16(Crc16Mode mode)
    {
        ushort polynomial = (ushort)mode;
        ushort value;
        ushort temp;
        for (ushort i = 0; i < table.Length; ++i)
        {
            value = 0;
            temp = i;
            for (byte j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            {
                if (((value ^ temp) & 0x0001) != 0)
                {
                    value = (ushort)((value >> 1) ^ polynomial);
                }
                else {
                    value >>= 1;
                }
                temp >>= 1;
            }
            table[i] = value;
        }
    }
}

       public byte[] getPreCRC16Bytes()
    {
            byte[] x = new byte[28];
            byte[] cmdBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.cmd.ToString());
            byte[] arg1Bytes = (byte[])this.arg1;
            byte[] arg2Bytes = (byte[])this.arg2;
            byte[] arg3Bytes = (byte[])this.arg3;
            byte[] arg4Bytes = (byte[])this.arg4;
            byte[] bodyLen = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
            byte[] emptyCRC = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
            byte[] checksum = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.checksum);
            var list = new List<byte>();
            list.AddRange(cmdBytes);
            list.AddRange(arg1Bytes);
            list.AddRange(arg2Bytes);
            list.AddRange(arg3Bytes);
            list.AddRange(arg4Bytes);
            list.AddRange(bodyLen);
            list.AddRange(emptyCRC);
            list.AddRange(checksum);
            var xx = list.ToArray();

        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(cmdBytes).Replace("-", "");

        return list.ToArray();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that one example, it appears to be the [X-25 16-bit CRC](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/all.htm#crc.cat.x-25), not the CCITT (Kermit) 16-bit CRC. There is a 1/65536 chance that this is a coincidence, since there is only one example, so you'd need to try it with several more sniffed packets.

Here is a simple, bit-at-a-time C routine that calculates that CRC (calling it with `mem == NULL` returns the initial value for the CRC):

```
unsigned crc16x_25_bit(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    crc = ~crc;
    crc &= 0xffff;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= *data++;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8408 : crc >> 1;
    }
    crc ^= 0xffff;
    return crc;
}
```

That code was generated by [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany), which also generates code for table-driven versions, both byte-wise and word-wise.

Comment: No, it should be straightforward to translate. Or you can just modify the code in your question. `polynomial` is `0x8408`. The initial value for `crc` is `0xffff` instead of `0`. Instead of `return crc;`, put in `return crc ^ 0xffff;`. That should do it. Your posted code does not have a polynomial anywhere in it, so you need to initialize the class with the polynomial. Or it would be better to just make that a constant in the code.